# Serving up a URL rewrite through a directory-specifc Web.Config

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a third-party `Javascript` software package that jumps through some hoops to connect a client to a back-end server for a chat session. It figures out the back-end server's address by pointing at a directory on the webserver that contains a web.config with a `URL` rewrite rule that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://myServer:1234/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I want to serve up this `Javascript` through an `MVC.Net` application to handle some user setup that needs to happen so I can pass some custom parameters through. The trouble is that when the `JS` tries to request the subdirectory containing the web.config with the rewrite rule, `MVC` (understandably) steps in and tries to match that request to a controller/action combo.

I *could* just create a controller with appropriately named actions to respond to the URL, but I don't think serving up the `web.config's` contents as literal text is going to solve my problem. My understanding is that `IIS` reads any web.configs in a directory when that directory is requested and applies any rules found in the config to the request.

How should I go about telling `MVC` to get out of the way for this request so `IIS` can do its thing as expected? Am I even making the correct assumptions, or am I totally off-base?

For example's sake, the URL for the directory in question would be something like `http://somesite.com/Server1/`, and in the file system a Server1 folder would exist in the site root containing only the web.config detailed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting up your routes, add:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Server1/{*.pathInfo}");
```

Comment: I had it in my head that even if I managed to get it to route to the appropriate directory, MVC would've still refused to allow IIS to process the web.config. In retrospect, that doesn't make any sense. Thanks for the quick, concise reply. That worked just as intended.